# Handling push notifications when user enables them in Settings after initially denying access

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about remote push notifications and how other developers handle a specific scenario. (I use Fireabase Messaging for remote push notificaiton just FYI.)

I need to handle a situation where a user initially denies push notification authorization using the [requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization) method. The user then goes to the Settings app, turns on notifications for my app using the "Allow Notifications" toggle, and returns to my app.

If the user kills and relaunches the app, they can receive remote push notifications since all code in the app delegate runs again when relaunched. However, if the user doesn't relaunch my app after changing the Settings, they won't receive remote notifications in my app.

Specifically, here is the flow:

1. User installs my app
2. User goes to the notifications tab in my app and is asked for push
   notification permission
3. User taps "Don't Allow"
4. User goes to the Settings app and turns on the "Allow Notifications"
   toggle for my app
5. User returns to my app (if they have relaunched my app, they can receive notificaiton)

Ideally, I would like the user to be able to receive remote notifications after changing the Settings, without having to kill and relaunch the app.

Is it possible to make push notifications work in this scenario without relaunching the app? For example, could calling [UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications) when the app enters the foreground handle this case?

Any insights on how to best handle this user flow would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // save device token
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String, error: Error) {
        print("didFailToContinueUserActivityWithType: \(error)")
    }
}

// MARK: - MessagingDelegate

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    // save fcm token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about push notifications, but rather the application lifecycle and `UIApplicationDelegate` methods responding to the lifecycle in general.

Whatever code you call in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` only runs when the app first starts or re-starts (after being "killed" by the user or iOS in background.)

If you need to run code every time the app becomes active, take a look at other parts of the `UIApplicationDelegate`'s API like [`applicationDidBecomeActive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive).

Answer (score 0):

Notification permissions are not for *push notifications*. They are to *show notifications*.

Your app will always receive a notification token if call `registerForRemoteNotifications()`

If your app has not requested and received (or the user has subsequently removed) notification permissions then any push notifications your server sends will not be shown to the user.

So, the simplest approach is just to always call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`.

A more sophisticated approach would be to check the current notification permissions in `didBecomeActive` and if notification permissions have been removed and `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is `true` then you can unregister for remote notifications, but I do not recommend this approach.

Consider the following sequence:

- Notification permissions are granted
- Your app registers for remote notifications
- User removes notification permissions in settings
- User opens your app which then unregisters for remote notifications
- Some time later user adds permissions back in settings but does not go into your app

Now, they have enabled notifications but are not receiving push notifications because your app hasn't re-registered.

If you use the first approach of just always registering this isn't a problem. You send some push notifications that may not be shown to the user, but that isn't a big deal.